# Colors with enriched-mode

Tags: faces, enriched-mode

I am trying to use the enriched-mode for my personal documentation. I would like to colorize specific sections of my text for clarity. I can successfully do it with Edit/Text Properties/Foreground Color. The saved files seam to contain the right tags  etc. but the colors do not show up by reloading the file. Other features like italic/bold/etc. work fine. I cannot figure out why and how to solve this.
The original emacs buffer : "bold" is ... in bold font and "yellow" is yellow

```
standard
bold
yellow
end
```

The content of the file:

```
Content-Type: text/enriched
Text-Width: 98

standard

<bold>bold

</bold><x-color><param>yellow</param>yellow</x-color>

end
```

When reloading, only the "bold" line has the right face, the color is gone.

Comment: Are you using a theme for Emacs? I know one of the themes I use doesn't allow for bold fonts, so they do not show up with enriched text. Also check the variable `enriched-translations`, since the docs say "Enriched mode does not save all Emacs text properties, only those specified in the variable enriched-translations. These include properties for fonts, colors, indentation, and justification."

Comment: No, I just tried the enriched mode. The colors are actually saved in the file but do not get restored when re-reading.

Comment: It is hard to see what is happening without having more information about what you have in your file. Colors work fine for me. I suggest you edit your question to add the text you are having trouble with. Additionally, read this page and follow the example: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EnrichedMode

Comment: Thank you Ghuilherme. I have updated my post. Hope it is understandable. Th e example in your link says nothing about colors.

Answer (score 2):

your example works fine for me with **Emacs version 26.1**.
I'll tell you what I did and try to follow along.

`C-x C-f` a new file, say `test.txt`, and copy the contents below into it:

```
Content-Type: text/enriched
Text-Width: 98

standard

<bold>bold

</bold><x-color><param>yellow</param>yellow</x-color>

end
```

Then do `M-x enriched-mode` and `C-x C-s` to save the file.
Then `C-x C-v RET` to reload the `test.txt` file, and it should show you this:
[image]

Now, I've noticed that depending on the theme the bold face may be hardly noticeable, and, if you are on a Mac, that it works better on some versions of Emacs than others (better in [Macports](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=emacs) version, for example).

If it is not working for you, maybe try dropping your `init.el` file, if you have one, or try another Emacs version.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Guilherme. No way, I cannot get the color to work. I am using Emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried dropping my .emacs config file which contains a few personal staff but no change. Anyway, I think I will switch to the org-mode that offers a lot of nice features and forget about the enriched-mode. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pierre I don't personally use enriched-mode, and I think you can achieve most of what you need in orgmode. And, if you need colored text, you can export your files to html for example, or use the markups available in orgmode. Still, I find it weird that it is not working on your Emacs, try updating it to 26.1.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé Your suggestion to use Emacs 26.1 works for [Eduardo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/21744/eduardo) as answer to [his question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48046/colors-do-not-get-saved). I transferred this important information from [your comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44057/colors-with-enriched-mode/44110#comment67734_44110) to the answer. I hope the answer is correct in this form and you agree with the edit. I have marked [the other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48046/2370) as duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Tobias thanks for the edit, it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be an old question, but the lack of color might come from font lock mode. Try to disable it and check colors