# Colors do not get saved

Tags: colors, enriched-mode

I want to color a word in emacs. So I open a `somefile` (C-x C-f somefile) and a write `some silly sentence`.

Now I want to colorize the word silly with yellow. So, with the mouse I chose `Edit > Text Properties > Other` and in the mini-buffer I write `yellow`.

Finally I save the file (C-x C-f) and close it (C-x k).

Now when I open the file again, the word silly will not appear in yellow.

The result is the same whether `enriched-mode` is set or not.

Can someone please explain me why?

This post is similar to the one found here [Colors with enriched-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44057/colors-with-enriched-mode) which has no accepted answer and (unfortunately) a downvote, but no good explanation and that's the reason I post this question.

I'm running emacs 25.1.1.

Comment: The quasi-answer in a [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44057/colors-with-enriched-mode#comment67734_44110) of the [linked question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44057/colors-with-enriched-mode) is to use emacs 26.1. Can you update? The example there works for me in emacs 26.1.

Comment: Have you *tried* `enriched-mode`? That's what it's for. See the Emacs manual, node [Enriched Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Enriched-Text.html). If you tried it and you had a problem, please specify your problem. Otherwise the question is not clear, so far.

Comment: @Tobias: thanks, it works. Please answer the post and I gladly accept your answer!

Comment: I've stressed Emacs version 26.1 in the [answer to the linked question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44110/2370) and voted to close this question as duplicate. Thanks for testing!